# Is it possible to have event-driven programs without using loops?

Tags: loops, events, event-handling, listener

It seems for low level reactive systems a loop that constantly listens to check for user input can create a bit of overhead. I'm curious, is it possible to have a program that sort of has a true stand-by mode where it has no overhead in waiting until a user gives it an input. I'm thinking of something analogous to a series of stacked dominoes that require no overhead to constantly maintain but could be toppled in a certain way via an input by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Typically event driven programming is not dependent on polling loops at all.
Generally you attach your event to a delegate which is called specifically from another chunk of code (the thing that raises the event). The only real loop involved is because you can have many subscribers on the delegate so you need to loop them to call them but that's it. Now something listening for say command line input is probably using a polling loop but that is not actually event programming.

```
public string Input
{
    set
    {
        if(!string.isnullorempty(value))
        {
          this.input = value;
          callInputAddedEvents(value);//this loops a list of delegates to call them
        }
    }
}
```